# Which method should be used if I want to find relations between two variables

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, k-means, duplicate-records

Assume that you have a matrix $X \in \Re^{M x N}$ that have $M$ rows and $N$ columns. The rows $M$ can vary in length, but the $N$ columns remains constant.

Each row is labeled with a class ID. The data is 8-bit in this case. The data looks like this. Notice that there are three data rows that have the same value. The are marked red.

[image]

The problem with this, is that these rows have the same value and they shares but they are labled with different class ID.

**Question:**

If I want to use multiple Support Vector Machine to classify this. What do I need to do before I can classify the data?

My idea is to use K-means clustering, where I can create new separate class ID labels.
In this case, I create 3 clusters.

So if I get like an unkown data table with $M$ rows and $N$ columns that is for one class, but I don't know. So if I classify that with multiple Support vector machine, and I get both class 1, class 2 and class 3. Then I can determine with some probility what the unknown data belongs to.

Is that possible to achieve with K-means clustering or do I need to add another algorithm more?